# MongoDB - distinct and count, the simplest case

Tags: mongodb, count, distinct, mlab

I have database XXX and collection YYY in MongoDB (using MongoLab).

Here is a sample record:

```
{
 "_id": {
    "$oid": "551a5asdfsdfsdfs"
 },
 "_class": "com.test.com",
 "mvid": "d0fffsdfs"

}
```

I would like to retrieve all distinct values of the field "mvid" and count them. 
Here is what found on the internet:

```
db.YYY.aggregate([{ $group: { _id: "$mvid"}  },{ $group: { _id: 1, count: { $sum: 1 } } }])
```

I also tried

```
XXX.YYY.aggregate([{ $group: { _id: "$mvid"}  },{ $group: { _id: 1, count: { $sum: 1 } } }])
```

I put the above into command text box, in both cases I get the following error message: "We encountered an error while parsing your JSON. Please check your syntax (e.g. ensure you are using double quotes around both your field names and values) and try again."

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is the same example, but issue is different. Now I am using command window and dealing with aggregation. I assume command window and the shell are the same.

Comment: The hint says, "ensure you are using double quotes around both your field names and values". I see lots of field names without any double quotes around them.

Comment: @IMSoP, I would like to aggregate by "mvid" field. This is the only field and it is in double quotes in my example.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think the fields it's talking about are the keys in your query, like $group, _id, etc

Comment: @JohnnyHK, you answered it again. I wish MongoLab error messages would be more informative. I installed shell on my PC, but it turns I need a permission to connect via shell. Well, this is question for DB admin. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That command text box is for providing JSON-formatted parameters to whatever command is selected in the drop-down. `aggregate` is not one of the listed commands, so it appears that you'd need to install the MongoDB shell locally and then remotely connect to your MongoLab database and run the command.

See [this blog post](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2530-getting-started-with-mongolab-and-the-mongodb-shell.htm) for details on installing the MongoDB shell and connecting to MongoLab.

Answer (score 2):

For finding the counts by each mvid:

`db.YYY.aggregate([{$group: {_id: "$mvid", count: {$sum: 1}}}])`

For finding the count of distinct mvids:

`db.YYY.aggregate([{$group: {_id: "$mvid", count: {$sum: 1}}}, {$group: {_id: null, count: {$sum: 1}}}, {$project: {_id: 0, count: 1}}])`

Comment: Wow, this is really complicated! What is the philosophy behind this expression (I mean the second one)? Is there good tutorial on aggregate statement? Thank you for posting it!

Comment: you mean the aggregation pipeline ? well, we have the 1st group which is doing the count by each mvid, and then the 2nd group expression works on this and produces the count of distinct and then since we were interested only in count using project operation to do just that. I found the [doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/interface/) on mongodb officical site useful.